# Pyqtgraph ColorBarItem Add String Next to Number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

The following code is a simple modification of the `pyqtgraph` example "Matrix Display".

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets, mkQApp

class MyBar(pg.ColorBarItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kargs)
        self.unit = "cm"
        self.display_unit()
    
    def display_unit(self):
        pass

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """ example application main window """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        gr_wid = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
        self.setCentralWidget(gr_wid)
        self.resize(600,500)
        self.show()

        bar = MyBar( values=(-1,1), colorMap=None)
        gr_wid.addItem(bar)

mkQApp("")
main_window = MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```

I have `PyQt5` and `pyqtgraph` installed in my environment. The code runs and gives:

[image]

I would like to write a method to add units to my bar. Given a string `unit`, in this case `"cm"`, I want to achieve any one of two, preferably within this class `MyBar`, that:

1. The unit gets displayed beside the top number:

[image]

2. Add a string, as a title above the whole bar or closely above the top number, which says "unit = cm":

[image]

Remark that I am only asking to display an additional string. Nothing in terms of functionality of the bar should change. I tried to go through the source code but had found no way helpful to achieve this.

Comment: while it is not exactly what you are looking for, you can try using the `label` argument at initialization to set a horizontal label _next_ to the colorbar.

Comment: If I do that, wouldn't the label be too far away from the colorbar?

Comment: `bar = MyBar(values=(-1, 1), colorMap=None, label="unit = cm")`. The label is placed on the opposite side of the colorbar's numbers, so it is a bit far, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a "proper" way to get this to work. pyqtgraph has a built-in automatic handling for axis units, which automatically scales units to the correct SI prefix  ('m' for milli-, 'k' for kilo-, etc...). So you just need to grab the `ColorBarItem`'s main axis and give it an appropriate unit.

The one caveat is that 'c' for centi- is not considered an SI prefix py pyqtgraph - it'll automatically go for milli- instead. So, if you want to force it to use "cm" and forego any autoscaling fanciness, you need to call `enableAutoSIPrefix(False)` on the axis.

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets, mkQApp


class MyBar(pg.ColorBarItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, units=None, **kargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kargs)

        if units is not None:
            self.set_units(units)

    def set_units(self, units):
        self.axis.setLabel(units=units)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """ example application main window """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        gr_wid = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True)
        self.setCentralWidget(gr_wid)
        self.resize(600, 500)
        self.show()

        bar = MyBar(values=(-0.01, 0.01), colorMap=None, units="m")
        gr_wid.addItem(bar)


mkQApp("")
main_window = MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```

[image: output]